# QGIS 3.8 - Logging changes to file

Tags: qgis, python, desktop-gis, logging

Is there a way to log data about changes provided by user to file? I want to log which user made a certain change, when this change occurred and the content of this change.

Use case:

1. User logged in my QGIS app.
2. User made some changes (e.g.: deleted some line)
3. Details about change was saved to file (e.g.: log.txt)

Comment: Are you talking about change in a QGIS project or change in a layer ?, if it's the project you should look at some version control system (like Git), if its about layer it's versioning.

Comment: make your users use a database with logging enabled - force them to use there own username/passwords

Comment: @J.R - I ment that i want to log each layer modification and bind this info with the user who is responsible for particular change. Specially changes done by GUI. Mappez - Do you mean that enabling logging to concrete file on my db is going to log all changes to the file ? Even those made with GUI ?